# Why doesn't groupby sum convert boolean to int or float?

Tags: python, pandas

I'll start with 3 simple examples:

```
pd.DataFrame([[True]]).sum()

0    1
dtype: int64
```

---

```
pd.DataFrame([True]).sum()

0    1
dtype: int64
```

---

```
pd.Series([True]).sum()

1
```

---

All of these are as expected.  Here is a more complicated example.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
        ['a', 'A', True],
        ['a', 'B', False],
        ['a', 'C', True],
        ['b', 'A', True],
        ['b', 'B', True],
        ['b', 'C', False],
    ], columns=list('XYZ'))

df.Z.sum()

4
```

Also as expected.  However, if I `groupby(['X', 'Y']).sum()`

[image]

I expected it to look like:

[image]

I'm thinking bug.  Is there another explanation?

---

Per @unutbu's answer

pandas is trying to recast as original dtypes.  I had thought that maybe the group by I'd performed didn't really groupby anything.  So I tried this example to test out the idea.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
        ['a', 'A', False],
        ['a', 'B', False],
        ['a', 'C', True],
        ['b', 'A', False],
        ['b', 'B', False],
        ['b', 'C', False],
    ], columns=list('XYZ'))
```

I'll `groupby('X')` and `sum`.  If @unutbu is correct, these sums should be `1` and `0` and are castable to `bool`, therefore we should see `bool`

```
df.groupby('X').sum()
```

[image]

Sure enough... `bool`

But if the process is the same but the values are slightly different.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
        ['a', 'A', True],
        ['a', 'B', False],
        ['a', 'C', True],
        ['b', 'A', False],
        ['b', 'B', False],
        ['b', 'C', False],
    ], columns=list('XYZ'))

df.groupby('X').sum()
```

[image]

lesson learned.  Always use `astype(int)` or something similar when doing this.

```
df.groupby('X').sum().astype(int)
```

gives consistent results for either scenario.

Comment: I'd probably call it a bug too, especially because you get what you expect after `df['Z'] = df['Z'].astype(int)`. Go report it and see if the developers of `pandas` have a reason for this behavior.

Comment: This occurs because [`_cython_agg_blocks`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/groupby.py#L3128) calls `_try_coerce_and_cast_result` which calls [`_try_cast_result`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/internals.py#L536) which tries to return a result *of the same dtype* as the original values (in this case, `bool`).

Comment: @unutbu I can see the merit of that decision.  However, that seems to imply that when using group aggregation, we should always cast as the type we expect. Question, could you post this as an answer so it appears as answered?  Thx!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This occurs because [`_cython_agg_blocks`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/groupby.py#L3128) calls `_try_coerce_and_cast_result` which calls [`_try_cast_result`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/internals.py#L536) which tries to return a result *of the same dtype* as the original values (in this case, `bool`).

This returns something a little peculiar when `Z` has dtype bool (and all the groups have no more than one True value). If any of the groups have 2 or more True values, then the resulting values are floats since  `_try_cast_result` does not convert 2.0 back to a boolean.

`_try_cast_result` does something more useful when `Z` has dtype `int`: Internally, the Cython aggregator used by 
`df.groupby(['X', 'Y']).sum()` returns a `result` of dtype `float`. Here then, `_try_cast_result` returns the result to dtype `int`.

Comment: So, then? Is the bug fixed? I'm having the same problem with pandas version 1.2.4