# Control dtype of aggregation results

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, group-by, aggregate-functions

When I do

```
df.groupby('id').aggregate({
    "timestamp": {
        "len" : len,
        ...
    },
    ....
})
```

I get `timestamp.len` column of type `datetime64` which is, obviously, *not* what I want.

How do I control this?

I can probably do some post-processing, like

```
res[('timestamp','len')].astype(int)
```

but I would rather get the right type right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah!  That's weird.
Use `size` instead

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(id=['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'],
                       timestamp=pd.date_range('2016-09-29', periods=4)))

df.groupby('id').aggregate({'timestamp': {'len': 'size'}})
```

[image]

Comment: this is a workaround. are you implying that the behavior I observe is a (known?) bug?

Comment: @sds I think it's related to http://stackoverflow.com/a/38579754/2336654