# Pandas transform() vs apply()

Tags: python, pandas, transform, apply

I don't understand why `apply` and `transform` return different dtypes when called on the same data frame. The way I explained the two functions to myself before went something along the lines of "`apply` collapses the data, and `transform` does exactly the same thing as `apply` but preserves the original index and doesn't collapse." Consider the following.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,4],
                   'cat': [1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1]})
```

Let's identify those `id`s which have a nonzero entry in the `cat` column.

```
>>> df.groupby('id')['cat'].apply(lambda x: (x == 1).any())
id
1     True
2     True
3    False
4     True
Name: cat, dtype: bool
```

Great. If we wanted to create an indicator column, however, we could do the following.

```
>>> df.groupby('id')['cat'].transform(lambda x: (x == 1).any())
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    1
5    1
6    1
7    0
8    0
9    1
Name: cat, dtype: int64
```

I don't understand why the dtype is now `int64` instead of the boolean returned by the `any()` function.

When I change the original data frame to contain some booleans (note that the zeros remain), the transform approach returns booleans in an `object` column. This is an extra mystery to me since all of the values are boolean, but it's listed as `object` apparently to match the `dtype` of the original mixed-type column of integers and booleans.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,4],
                   'cat': [True,True,0,0,True,0,0,0,0,True]})

>>> df.groupby('id')['cat'].transform(lambda x: (x == 1).any())
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
5     True
6     True
7    False
8    False
9     True
Name: cat, dtype: object
```

However, when I use all booleans, the transform function returns a boolean column.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,4],
                   'cat': [True,True,False,False,True,False,False,False,False,True]})

>>> df.groupby('id')['cat'].transform(lambda x: (x == 1).any())
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
5     True
6     True
7    False
8    False
9     True
Name: cat, dtype: bool
```

Using my acute pattern-recognition skills, it appears that the `dtype` of the resulting column mirrors that of the original column. I would appreciate any hints about why this occurs or what's going on under the hood in the `transform` function. Cheers.

Comment: `apply` does not collapse the data. `apply` is flexible and can return a series or dataframe of any size. `transform` always preserves the number of rows for each group. `transform` also sends each individual column as a series to the calling function. `apply` sends the entire dataframe to the calling function.

Comment: [related](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38579754/2336654)

Comment: Aha! Thank you @piRSquared. I think I understand better why this is happening after reading that comment and looking at the source code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like `SeriesGroupBy.transform()` tries to cast the result dtype to the same one as the original column has, but `DataFrameGroupBy.transform()` doesn't seem to do that:

```
In [139]: df.groupby('id')['cat'].transform(lambda x: (x == 1).any())
Out[139]:
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    1
5    1
6    1
7    0
8    0
9    1
Name: cat, dtype: int64

#                         v       v
In [140]: df.groupby('id')[['cat']].transform(lambda x: (x == 1).any())
Out[140]:
     cat
0   True
1   True
2   True
3   True
4   True
5   True
6   True
7  False
8  False
9   True

In [141]: df.dtypes
Out[141]:
cat    int64
id     int64
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 6):

Just adding another illustrative example with sum as I find it more explicit:

```
df = (
    pd.DataFrame(pd.np.random.rand(10, 3), columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
        .assign(a=lambda df: df.a > 0.5)
)

Out[70]: 
       a         b         c
0  False  0.126448  0.487302
1  False  0.615451  0.735246
2  False  0.314604  0.585689
3  False  0.442784  0.626908
4  False  0.706729  0.508398
5  False  0.847688  0.300392
6  False  0.596089  0.414652
7  False  0.039695  0.965996
8   True  0.489024  0.161974
9  False  0.928978  0.332414

df.groupby('a').apply(sum)  # drop rows

         a         b         c
a                             
False  0.0  4.618465  4.956997
True   1.0  0.489024  0.161974


df.groupby('a').transform(sum)  # keep dims

          b         c
0  4.618465  4.956997
1  4.618465  4.956997
2  4.618465  4.956997
3  4.618465  4.956997
4  4.618465  4.956997
5  4.618465  4.956997
6  4.618465  4.956997
7  4.618465  4.956997
8  0.489024  0.161974
9  4.618465  4.956997
```

However when applied to `pd.DataFrame` and not `pd.GroupBy` object I was not able to see any difference.