# Pandas groupby changes return type when reassembling groups

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'c':[0,1,1,2,2,2],   'date':pd.to_datetime(['2016-01-01','2016-02-01','2016-03-01','2016-04-01','2016-05-01','2016-06-01'])})
```

For each row, I would like to get a number = the month number for each date (Jan=1,Feb=2 etc.) + length of that group (1st group having 1 member, 2nd group having 2 etc.):

So it should return something like:

```
c       date   num
0 2016-01-01    2
1 2016-02-01    4
1 2016-03-01    5
2 2016-04-01    7
2 2016-05-01    8
2 2016-06-01    9
```

I created a function:

```
def testlambda(x):
    print(x)
    return x.dt.month.astype('int') + len(x)
```

And used groupby + transform:

```
df['num'] = df.groupby(['c'])['date'].transform(lambda x: testlambda(x))
```

But the new column returned is still in date format, even if my lambda returns int.

What to do here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use `DataFrameGroupBy.transform()` instead of `SeriesGroupBy.transform()` as the latter one tries to cast the result to the source dtype:

```
In [131]: def testlambda(x):
     ...:     #print(x)
     ...:     return x.dt.month.astype('int') + len(x)
     ...:

In [132]: df
Out[132]:
   c       date
0  0 2016-01-01
1  1 2016-02-01
2  1 2016-03-01
3  2 2016-04-01
4  2 2016-05-01
5  2 2016-06-01

#                                      v        v - thats's the only difference    
In [133]: df['num'] = df.groupby(['c'])[['date']].transform(lambda x: testlambda(x))

In [134]: df
Out[134]:
   c       date  num
0  0 2016-01-01    2
1  1 2016-02-01    4
2  1 2016-03-01    5
3  2 2016-04-01    7
4  2 2016-05-01    8
5  2 2016-06-01    9
```

Comment: You are the man!!  Could you update the answer to use lambda? The real function is more complicated than a one-liner so I think calling a function is a more general solution.  But this is awesome.

Comment: I didn't know there was a difference between `DataFrameGroupBy.transform()` and `SeriesGroupBy.transform()`. Is that documented somewhere? The behavior on the series version is exactly what I was curious about [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41476436/pandas-transform-vs-apply).

Comment: @iwbabn, sure, i've edited my answer - i used your `testlambda()` function as it is

Comment: @3novak, i don't know whether it's documented - that was result of my observations...

Comment: Thanks, @MaxU. Would you mind dropping a response to [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41476436/pandas-transform-vs-apply) noting your observation on the difference in behavior?

Answer (score 1):

I'd avoid the `lambda` by using `size` within a `transform`

```
df.assign(num=df.groupby('c').c.transform('size') + df.date.dt.month)

   c       date  num
0  0 2016-01-01    2
1  1 2016-02-01    4
2  1 2016-03-01    5
3  2 2016-04-01    7
4  2 2016-05-01    8
5  2 2016-06-01    9
```