# Calculating median if for values in a column that match a condition

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Pandas.

My dataset:

df

```
A       B 
10      1
15      2  
65      3   
54      2  
51      2   
96      1
```

I am trying to add new column `C` and calculate the median for values that are in the same group defined by column `B`.

Expected result:

df

```
A       B       C
10      11      53
15      2       34
65      3       65
54      2       34
51      2       34
96      1       53
```

What I've tried:

```
df_final['C'] = df_final.groupby('B')['A'].transform('median')
```

I do get an answer, but due to big DataFrame I am unsure if my code performs correctly, could someone tell me if I am using the right way to achieve this?

Comment: I think solution is correct.

Comment: That is the correct way

Comment: Thanks, I've used your previous example @jezrael when you showed how to calculate average values for grouped categories. And if I want to extract the maximum and the minimum values from column `A` per category `B` I can use `df['max']=df.groupby('B')['A'].transform(max)`?

Comment: @JonasPalačionis - yop, it is good

Comment: @JonasPalačionis if jerzael's comment solved your problem, please mark the question as "closed".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas transform() vs apply()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41476436/pandas-transform-vs-apply)

Comment: That is a good piece of information, not directly related to my question though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
df_final['C'] = df_final.groupby('B')['A'].transform('median')
```

As provided in comments.