# GroupBy column cumsum returns bool instead of int

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'ts':[True, False],
     'user':['x', 'y'],
    'id': [1,2]})

df.set_index('id', inplace=True)

df.groupby('user').ts.cumsum()
```

**output**

```
id
1     True
2    False
Name: ts, dtype: bool
```

***GroupBy*** ***cumsum*** on a ***column*** yields bool instead of int if the group size is 1? I expected it to return 1 if the column is true and zero if the cell is false. Shouldn't a **sum** operation anyway return an integer?

***EDIT:***

on the other hand cumsum on dataframe returns int if the size is 1. Is there any rationale behind this inconsistency?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'ts':[False],
     'user':['x'],
    'id': [1]})

df.set_index('id', inplace=True)

df.ts.cumsum()
```

**output**

```
id
1    0
Name: ts, dtype: int64
```

Comment: `df.groupby('user').ts.cumsum().astype(int)` ?

Comment: yes I did that but I assumed a sum operation would return an int by default?

Comment: Actually it returns `bool` if all groups are of size one. If one of the groups is lager you'll get `float`.

Comment: Interesting question. Perform `cumsum` on a one-item series, i.e. `pd.Series([True]).cumsum()`, doesn't yield this behaviour (on v0.19.2).

Comment: I didn't check very carefully but looks like this was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38579297/why-doesnt-groupby-sum-convert-boolean-to-int-or-float)